# assert.isNotNull failing on unit test populated as part of scope

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and I am attempting to write a test that calls a controllers get action based on a GUID:

```
[TestClass]
public class DocumentControllerTests : TestBase
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory(Unit)]
    public void DocumentController_Get_Returns_Ok()
    {
        //
        // arrange
        //
        var scope = new DefaultScope();
        var expected = Builder<Dom.Document>
            .CreateListOfSize(1)
            .Build();
        scope.DocumentProviderMock
            .Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync())
            .ReturnsAsync(expected);

        //
        // act & assert
        //
        var testId = scope.TestId;
        var actual = scope.InstanceUnderTest.Get(testId)
            .AssertOk<List<Api.Document>>()
            .Content;
        expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actual, opt => opt.ExcludingMissingMembers());
    }
```

Here is the scope class defined:

```
    private class DefaultScope : TestScope<DocumentController>
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     initializes a new instance of the
        ///     Deloitte.DCIPP.Tests.Web.Service.DocumentStore.DocumentControllerTests.DefaultScope class.
        /// </summary>
        public DefaultScope()
        {
            LoggingProviderMock = new Mock<ILoggingProvider>();
            DocumentProviderMock = new Mock<IDocumentProvider>();
            DependencyResolverMock =
                MockDependencyResolverFor<IResourceUrlBuilder, ResourceUrlBuilder>(new ResourceUrlBuilder());
            TestId = Guid.NewGuid();

            TestWebDocument = Builder<Api.Document>
                .CreateNew()
                .Build();

            TestDocument = BuildDomainDocument(TestId);


            // use standard maps
            AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMaps(Mapper.Configuration, DependencyResolverMock);

            InstanceUnderTest = new DocumentController(DocumentProviderMock.Object, LoggingProviderMock.Object,
                Mapper.Engine);

            BootstrapControllerContext(InstanceUnderTest);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets or sets the dependency resolver mock.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The dependency resolver mock.</value>
        public IDependencyResolver DependencyResolverMock { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Log Category all messages will be associated with.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The expected log categories.</value>
        public LogCategories ExpectedLogCategories { get; } = LogCategories.DocumentStoreService;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets the logging provider mock.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The logging provider mock.</value>
        public Mock<ILoggingProvider> LoggingProviderMock { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets the Document provider mock.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The Document provider mock.</value>
        public Mock<IDocumentProvider> DocumentProviderMock { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets the identifier of the test.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The identifier of the test.</value>
        public Guid TestId { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets or sets the test Document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The test Document.</value>
        public Dom.Document TestDocument { get; set; }

        public Api.Document TestWebDocument { get; }

        public Dom.Document BuildDomainDocument(Guid expectedId)
        {
            // Invoke GetBytes method.
            var array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Byte Controller Test");

            return Builder<Dom.Document>
                .CreateNew()
                .With(x => x.Id, expectedId)
                .With(t => t.Data = array)
                .Build();
        }
    }
```

When I run the test I am getting an exception on line:

```
            .AssertOk<List<Api.Document>>()
```

Thhis method is called from another class but it's relatively straightforward. The error I am getting is that assert.isNotNull is failing:

[image]

I don't understand why it's null as I populate the scope before hand.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: My first guess would be that your httpActionResult is not of type OkNegotiatedResult<TContentType>. Check to see what the httpActionResult is

Comment: Do you mean this line might be the wrong object type? var actual = scope.InstanceUnderTest.Get(testId)

Comment: in your AssertOk method itself, there is a variable called httpActionResult which is the response from the Get request itself. If the value is a valid response, then you should get back an OkNegotiatedResult<TContentType> but it could be that you're getting a BadRequestResult or a NotFoundResult instead. When you debug, check to see what the type actually is. Likely, your cast is null b/c it's another type

Comment: I just check and yes it is NotFoundResult  instead. How would I fix this?

Comment: There could be a couple of issues here. 1. Is your ApiController implementation returning a NotFoundResult at all? If not, then it's not finding the route that you're calling. Check to see what the route it's calling and then try to hit that route with Fiddler or Postman